# Tetration fractal algorithm

Tags: complex-numbers, algorithms, exponentiation, fractals

In the code example at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577917-tetration-fractal/ the author seems to implement the operation of a complex number, $z=x+iy$, raised to the power of itself, $z^z$, as
$$
z^z = e^{-\pi y / 2}\left(\cos\frac{\pi x}{2} + i\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}\right).
$$
In my own implementation, I expressed $z = re^{i\theta}$ and got:
$$
z^z = \left(r^xe^{-y\theta}\right)\left[\cos(\theta x + y\ln r) + i\sin(\theta x + y\ln r)\right].
$$
How can these possibly be the same thing?

Comment: How can $z^z$ be always real. For example, if $z=e^{i\theta}=\text{cos}\theta +i\text{sin}\theta$, $z^z=$ isn't a real, because $z^z=e^{-\theta \text{sin}\theta}(e^{i\theta \text{cos}\theta})$.

Comment: @AlapanDas I think there was just an $i$ missing.

Comment: But what has $z^z$ become now? $=e^{-\frac{\pi y}{2}}(\text{cos}(\frac{\pi x}{2})+i\text{sin}(\frac{\pi x}{2}))=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(x+iy)}=i^{x+iy}$

Comment: Well, quite – so has the author of this algorithm got it wrong and my approach is right?

Comment: Can you share the image of the final result? I don't have Python and cannot read the code, so I cannot tell if the operation is valid. To produce the fractal you need to iterate as $z_{n+1}=z^{z_n}$ with $z$ fixed. This is not the same as the operation $z_{n+1}=z_n^{z_n}$, to which the operation $z^z$ applies.